# Find how many lines of code in VS2012 project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

How do I find how many lines of code are in my project/sub-project?

Comment: Who still uses lines of code as a metric?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn people who like to make fancy charts and graphs

Comment: @DMac the Destroyer Exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the menu bar, go to Analyze->Calculate Code Metrics for Project/Solution. This also gives you other information, such as a class's complexity, maintainability, depth of inheritance, and the number of class couplings.